# Dart chrome extension: How to send a response in onMessage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart

right now I'm developing a Chrome extension with Google's Dart.
All works fine, except the onMessage-handling.

Chrome-Package used: [API Ref.](http://dart-gde.github.io/chrome.dart/ext/) ~ [OnMessageEvent Ref.](http://dart-gde.github.io/chrome.dart/ext/chrome.runtime/OnMessageEvent.html)

In the background-script i'm calling:

```dart
import 'package:chrome/chrome_ext.dart' as chrome;


void main() {
  //...
  //Binde event-listeners
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.listen(onMessage);
  //...
}

/**
 * Message event handling
 */
bool onMessage(chrome.OnMessageEvent messageEvent){

  JsObject message = messageEvent.message;
  JsFunction response = messageEvent.sendResponse;

  switch(message['action']){

    //...

    //Used by popup
    case 'refresh':
      print('Refresh called!');
      chrome.storage.sync.get().then((_){
        new JsObject(response, [new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);
      });

      //Idicate to send a response asynchronously (So it's said in the OnMessageEvent Ref.)
      return true;

    //...
  }

  return false;
}
```

My popup-scripts looks like this:

```dart
//...
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  'action': "refresh"
}).then((_){
  print('receiving response!');
});
//...
```

What **is working**:
The message 'refresh' send from popup-script to background-script works!
The background-script prints `Refresh called!`

What **is not working**: 
The popup-script never receives the response called from the background-script: `new JsObject(response, [new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);`.

I don't know how to handel sendResponse to really send an response. Maybe my call with JsObject is wrong? Hope someone else can help.
(Btw. also a non async-response doesn't work here)

---

This problem is also open on [github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/150).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be in a way how you try to send the response back:

```dart
new JsObject(response, [new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);
```

According to the [dart.js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js.JsFunction@id_apply) docs, the function should in your case be invoked like:

```dart
response.apply([new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);
```

---

#### Update: here the working code:

background.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  print("main()...");
  context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'].callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);
}

void onMessageListener(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  print("received action = ${request['action']}");
  sendResponse.apply([new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);
}
```

popup.dart

```dart
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  print("main():...");
  context['chrome']['runtime'].callMethod('sendMessage', [new JsObject.jsify({'action': 'refresh'}), (response) => print("received ${response['done']}")]);
}
```

---

#### Update: required patch to make it working in JavaScript too

As mentioned in comments, there is a problem with the returned object from `context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage']` ... If it is not `JsObject` it should be wrapped into it by using `new JsObject.fromBrowserObject()`

```dart
var jsObject = context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'];
(jsObject is JsObject ? jsObject : new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(jsObject))
.callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);
```

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: As zoechi already mentioned on [github](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/150#issuecomment-36453868): "I tried response.apply([new JsObject.jsify({'done': true})]);
This doesn't lead to an exception but the provided JavaScript callback doesn't get called either."

Comment: I updated the answer with the working dart code. I am using the straight dart:js in favour of dart:chrome package

Comment: Works for me as well! Thx. Btw. also an async response works when returning true in the eventListener.

Comment: Is this working now?

I got a error when calling addListener.
"context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'].callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);"
"Uncaught TypeError: J.p(...).a0 is not a function"

My environments,
- Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)
- Dart VM version: 1.13.0 (Wed Nov 18 12:15:29 2015) on "macos_x64"

Comment: I got a error when calling addListener without dart2js minify.
This line: "context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'].callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);"
A error: "Uncaught TypeError: J.$index$asx(...).callMethod$2 is not a function"

Comment: I got a new solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631383/dart-chrome-extension-listen-to-chrome-api-events

Comment: Thx @ENDOHtakanao ... I also came across this problem on another project ... pity it is still unresolved in `datr2js` after more then a year reporting it.