# How do I register a listener for a onMessage event on a Port with chrome.dart

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dart

I have a chrome extension and I want to use the chrome.runtime.connect functionality to create a connection between my `pageAction` and the background page. I got stuck while trying to register a listener for the incoming messages.

My question is that I am looking for a working example of exchanging messages over a connection in chrome.dart.

I started by listening for newly created connections. `chrome.runtime.OnConnect` is an event stream, so I can just `listen`.

```dart
chrome.runtime.onConnect.listen((chrome.Port p) {
  ...
}
```

Now, the Port instances have an accessor `p.onMessage`, which is a `chrome.ChromeEvent` object. ChromeEvent instances provide a method with the following signature `Future addListener()`.

I tried messing around with the `p.onMessage` and also the value returned from the future returned after calling `p.onMessage.addListener`, but I got nowhere. I have no idea what to put instead of the three dots.

The only thing that works for me is looking into the [JavaScript API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) and emulateing with dart:js what they do there.

```dart
p.onMessage.jsProxy.callMethod('addListener', [listener]);
```

while of course having previously defined the `listener` function as

```dart
listener(message, s) {
  print('message: $message');
  print('message.runtimeType: ${message.runtimeType}');
  print('s: $s');
  print('s.runtimeType: ${s.runtimeType}');
  throw('halt');
}
```

I believe that the automatic API generation for Dart somehow messed up the API here.

There is actually a bug for this, https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/135

Comment: I'm stuck here too. I can register a listener but when I actually receive a message somewhere inside chrome scripts an exception is thrown. When I try to debug the exception is not thrown but the callback still doesn't get called. (https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/135, similar but uses runtime.onMessage https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/150, https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/163)

Comment: It helps to switch on "Pause on exceptions." and "Pause on caught exceptions" in the Dev Tools. My problem was that I originally had only one argument in my `listener` function and it was silently crashing on that.

Comment: Great, that works for me too! I can now send and receive on a port. I have yet to find out how to respond to a port message.

Comment: Really? You wrote in a comment under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114022/dart-chrome-extension-how-to-send-a-response-in-onmessage that Draško's workaround works for you.

Comment: That question was about `runtime.onMessage`, I have that working already, but I wasn't able to get `port.onMessage` working this way.

Comment: @user7610 have you managed to run your extension on Chrome too? This mixed approach worked fine in Dartium, but caused all sorts of problems when compiled to JavaScript.