# Dart chrome extension: Listen to chrome api events

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, dart2js, dart-js-interop

To better describe my problem i have created a small example of a chrome extension written in Dart.
You can see the code or download the extension on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/andigehle/a09ac9b765097bb84a65).

**The problem**

This example is running fine in Dartium, but when compiled to javascript a typeerror occurs: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for the line:

```dart
context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'].callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);
```

**How far i already am**

- As you may see in the example the functions `alert()` or `console.log()` via `dart:js` are also working in the js-extension. *So it could be a special problem with dart2js and adding eventlisteners?*
- Also printing out `context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage']` shows the right event-object. (E.g.: `context['console'].callMethod('log', [context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage']]);`)
- I know that there exist an chrome pub package, but there is still a bug when responding to received messages in onMessage. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114022/dart-chrome-extension-how-to-send-a-response-in-onmessage). Using the chrome api directly via dart:js was the workaround which was fine at that dart version.

---

I played a lot with the code but all results in the same error. Now i am out of ideas. Hope the community can help me again.

**Edit:**
I have now reported this bug on [dartbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20800) as Robert suggested.
Anyway, I'm still open for a workaround or something if someone know one.

Comment: Andi, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193392/issue-with-chrome-runtime-onconnect-when-building-chrome-extension-in-dart. It worked for me.

Comment: Yeah! Very thanks. I already knew that thread but didn't recognized that it was about the same problem. Got stuck at this bug for month ... Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **keerti** already mentioned: A similar problem with a workaround can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193392/issue-with-chrome-runtime-onconnect-when-building-chrome-extension-in-dart).

My solution looks like this:

```dart
  //Tmp: sendResponse is buged, so we use the js-version
  //chrome.runtime.onMessage.listen(onMessageDartListener);

  //..and ofcourse the js-version is buged too. So this workaround here:
  var jsOnMessageEvent = context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'];
  JsObject dartOnMessageEvent = (jsOnMessageEvent is JsObject ? jsOnMessageEvent : new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(jsOnMessageEvent));
  dartOnMessageEvent.callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);
```

Answer (score 3):

So your example is working fine for me:

```dart
//Placed in web/

import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  //This doesnt work in js
  context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage'].callMethod('addListener', [onMessageListener]);
  context['chrome']['runtime'].callMethod('sendMessage', ['someMessage']);
  context['chrome']['runtime'].callMethod('sendMessage', [null, 'someMessage']);
}


void onMessageListener(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  print("test");
  print(message);
}
```

Output

```dart
test (:1)
someMessage (:1)
test (:1)
someMessage (:1)
```

Regards,
Robert

// Sorry missed the exception you get

You should file a bug about this at www.dartbug.com

Regards,
Robert

// For now you should be able to use the chrome package. It works fine here:

```dart
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:chrome/chrome_ext.dart' as chrome;

void onMessageListener(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  print("test");
  print(message);
}

void main() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.listen((chrome.OnMessageEvent event) {
    print(event.message);
  });

  JsObject runtime = context['chrome']['runtime'];
  runtime.callMethod('sendMessage', ['someMessage']);
  runtime.callMethod('sendMessage', [null, 'someMessage']);
}
```

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Have you compiled the example to Js? The dart-version works for me as well, but not the compiled Js-version.

Comment: Nope that was my mistake. Debugging right now. Give me a second :)

Comment: So the error comes from the addListener access. But I cant tell you why at the moment.

Comment: That's right. My results are similar. As described above: chrome.runtime.onMessage can be accessed. `context['console'].callMethod('log', [context['chrome']['runtime']['onMessage']]);` prints the Event-object. But calling addListiner on the object breaks the extension :(

Comment: To your edit "For now you should be able to use the chrome package": As said in the question, i used `chrome.runtime.onMessage.listen` but the package has a bug in the **responding-functionality** which i also want to use. That was the main reason i switch to the js-interop variant. Sadly also using dart:js instead of chrome(-package) points me this bug. (For the chrome-package bug see also the posted [issue](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/150) long time ago)

Comment: Looks like you just can file a bug here.